# Count Element or Sum Element on PHP

Tags: php, count, sum, element

I have this TXT File

```
Jose,Manuel
Maria,Antonia
Petra,Guzman
Josefa,Perdomo
```

etc...

And this Script

```
<?
        $lines = file("./lista.txt") or die("No encuentro BD!");
        $url_letra="a";
        foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
        if(strpos($line,",")==0){
            $obser=$line;
        }else{
            $datos = explode(",", $line);
            $url_bd=$url_letra."|".$datos[1];
            echo count($datos[1]);
        }
    }?>
```

This Script print "1111" but I need count element or sum element. For me the correct answer is 4 is i count element. Could help to get this number 4. Thx

Comment: `$counter = $counter + 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the elements in the array using the count function. You are getting all the line (CSV) and exploding it into an array, then you can count the total elements on the array with count. (also you have 5 elements not 4).

I updated your code, please test and let me know. Hope it helps.

```
<?php
 $lines = file("./lista.txt") or die("No encuentro BD!");
 $total = 0;      

    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
       $datos = explode(",", $line);
       $url_bd=$url_letra."|".$datos[1];

       $total += count($datos[1]);
    }

print "Total: $total ";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter and increase it when required:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
    if(strpos($line,",")==0){
        $obser=$line;
    }else{
        $datos = explode(",", $line);
        $url_bd=$url_letra."|".$datos[1];
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code and you're good to go.
In your code, you print all the line not somme it like.
To get the numbers lines of code `count(file("./lista.txt"));` should work.

```
...
$count = 0
if(strpos($line,",")==0){
  $obser=$line;
}else{
  $datos = explode(",", $line);
  $url_bd=$url_letra."|".$datos[1];

  $count += count($datos[1]);
}
echo $count;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<?
    $lines = file("./lista.txt") or die("No encuentro BD!");
    $url_letra="a";
    foreach($lines as $line_num => $line){
     if(strpos($line,",")==0){
        $obser=$line;
     }else{
        $datos = explode(",", $line);
        $url_bd=$url_letra."|".$datos[1];
        $result += count($datos[1]);
     }

   }
   echo $result;
```

?>